# Please rate the degree of realism of the climate zones of this world

Tags: climate, geography

*English is not my native language so I apologize for possible mistakes*

The World is an Earth-like planet with a supercontinent in the northern hemisphere. Rodinia taken as the basis of the land mass. The location based on Pannonia.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am perplexed by

- having subequatorial climate all around the equator with the exception of the places with dry land. I would expect equatorial climate all around.
- the double cold currents in the first chart: why would the flow go South when there is no physical obstacle to it?
- again about currents, a warm current starting shortly South from the polar circle seems rather odd.
- for the same current of the previous bullet point: how can it stop in a dead end?

Comment: I apologize. I will try to answer your questions.

1. I used the Climatic zones of the Earth according to Alisov. Their meaning is in the dominance of certain air masses in a particular region.

2. My mistake. This is an artifact of the previous location of the land. You're right. there must of course be one cold current.

3-4. I agree. This is the weakest point of the map. I made a few mistakes in the currents.

Thanks for the comment.

Comment: https://lt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alisovo_klimato_klasifikacija

Here you can find a map of climatic zones according to Alisov. I'm sorry, but there is no English version.

Comment: @Laurin: That map indicates that Dublin, London, and Paris have the same climate as Sankt Petersburg, Severodvinsk, and Novosibirsk, placing the British Isles and Siberia in the same climate zone. I would not put much trust on it.

Comment: Oh, yeah... It looks wrong. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

There are periods in the history of earth when the continents were closer together like this, though not any with all the land in the northern hemisphere. One problem with large landmasses is that they can get very dry and barren in the center, I think your map works well in that sense.

Take a look at Earth during the Permian. (https://www.britannica.com/place/Pangea)

[image: Map of the Earth during the Late Permian showing the Panthalassic Ocean from https://www.britannica.com/place/Pangea]

Your big world-spanning ocean reminds me of the Panthalassic Ocean. But all of your landmasses are in the north hemisphere... or is it that this is just the "known world" ?

Large oceans can have terrible storms. The Earth has generally been much hotter without polar regions when there has been a Panthalassic Ocean-- but, the most confusing thing is that all the land is north of the equator for me.

EDIT:

Hmmm maybe the Carboniferous? The land masses were lopsided to the south to a degree, though not as extreme in your world. The Carboniferous was very hot and wet and there was extra O2 in the atmosphere which caused giant insects and other wonderful things.

[image: The Carboniferous]

Comment: This map showed the entire landmass of this world. The southern hemisphere is the ocean (not counting the small land near the equator). Big storms are part of this world. According to my idea, hurricanes, tornadoes and similar climatic phenomena are frequent events. Maybe you know of possible examples of worlds with land only in the polar region?

Comment: I've added the carboniferous, which could be a jumping off point for research.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like it's really like my world.